# Protecting the login page

Tags: php, drupal, .htaccess, drupal-6, content-management-system

I'm trying to add extra security to my drupal site. I removed the login block, but it can also be accessed through http://mydrupalsite.com/user

It's still needed to allow the admin account in, but is there a way to protect this single page with htaccess or something more robust than what drupal allows out of the box?

Comment: Protect it how? How will user 1 log in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Googletorp that a strong password is the best protection, but you can do more. The [restrict_by_ip](http://drupal.org/project/restrict_by_ip) module says to restrict access to the login page by IP address. The [login_security](http://drupal.org/project/login_security) module offers similar functionality and even more. I haven't used either of them, so I can't tell you if they work as advertised.

Answer (score 5):

How it can it possibly be more robust. If you have a strong password that should be enough. The only extra security you could add that would make sense is brute force protection. But if you have a strong password brute force should be impossible.

Comment: Agreed--there's no reason to "protect" the login form if you have a strong password. You might also want to disable public registrations (in admin/user/settings), but if your permissions are set up correctly, that shouldn't even be a problem, since there would be nothing for a newly registered user to do once he or she was logged in.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to protect this single
>   page with htaccess?

Yes. You can add an Apache Username and password to any path. It is a little tricky to set up and probably not worth it in this instance as a strong password will do the trick (as noted by others).

Have a look [here](http://www.elated.com/articles/password-protecting-your-pages-with-htaccess/), for what looks like a good how to.